# Cannot Autowire Service into Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring application and I am trying to autowire my service into my controller but it keeps returning the same error:

Error:  No matching bean of type [org.sims.service.SIMSService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

As if it cannot find the service bean.  I am defining my service bean in a file that is called spring-service.xml which is specied in my web.xml file.  At this point I took out all the code from the service because I just want the service to load but it is still not loading

Here is my service:

```
package org.sims.service;
public interface SIMSService {}
```

Here is my Service impl:

```
package org.sims.service.impl;

public class SIMSServiceImpl implements SIMSService{}
```

Here is my controller:

```
package org.sims.web.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/glossarySearchResults")
public class GlossarySearchController 
{

@Autowired
private SIMSService simsService = null;
```

Here is my spring-service.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="simsService" class="org.sims.service.impl.SIMSServiceImpl">
    <!-- <property name="glossarySearchDao" ref="glossarySearchDao" /> -->      
</bean>

</beans>
```

My web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>sims</display-name>
<description>sims</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:spring-resources.xml,
        classpath:spring-dao.xml,
        classpath:spring-service.xml,
        classpath:spring-security.xml,   
        classpath:spring-validation.xml, 
        classpath:spring-email.xml  
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>sims</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/spring-controllers.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>sims</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

<filter>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>sims</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error/401</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/404</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/500</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>504</error-code>
    <location>/error/504</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error/500</location>
</error-page>

</web-app>
```

In my spring-controllers.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.sims.web.controller" />
```

Here is the full error with additional lines..the log level is set to debug:

```
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.781] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@dc3491: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,glossarySearchController,homeGlossaryController,mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,exceptionMapping,xmlViewResolver,urlViewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.781] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0'
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.781] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry] Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'glossarySearchController'
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.781] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory] Creating instance of bean 'glossarySearchController'
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.796] [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata] Found injected element on class [org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController]: AutowiredFieldElement for private org.sims.service.SIMSService org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController.simsService
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.796] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory] Eagerly caching bean 'glossarySearchController' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.796] [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata] Processing injected method of bean 'glossarySearchController': AutowiredFieldElement for private org.sims.service.SIMSService org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController.simsService
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.812] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@dc3491: defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,glossarySearchController,homeGlossaryController,mainController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#1,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#2,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#3,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#3,exceptionMapping,xmlViewResolver,urlViewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
[2011-10-07 16:32:14.812] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'glossarySearchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.sims.service.SIMSService org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController.simsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.sims.service.SIMSService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1161)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:981)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4069)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4373)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:761)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5310)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:297)
at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:83)
at org.jboss.web.WebModule.startService(WebModule.java:61)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy45.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebContainer.start(AbstractWebContainer.java:466)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
at org.jboss.system.InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.invokeNext(InterceptorServiceMBeanSupport.java:238)
at org.jboss.ws.integration.jboss42.DeployerInterceptor.start(DeployerInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptorSupport$XMBeanInterceptor.start(SubDeployerInterceptorSupport.java:188)
at org.jboss.deployment.SubDeployerInterceptor.invoke(SubDeployerInterceptor.java:95)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy46.start(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:610)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.loop(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:274)
at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.run(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:225)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.sims.service.SIMSService org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController.simsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.sims.service.SIMSService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:502)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:282)
... 108 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.sims.service.SIMSService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:920)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:789)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:474)
... 110 more
```

Comment: please add the web.xml, and the part of the configuration file that does the component scan to find the controller. I guess the problem is in one of this files.

Comment: Strange--that all looks correct. What ApplicationContext is being started when you get the error? Show more of the error in context with several lines of the log before it happens.

Comment: Also, how are you building and running the app?

Comment: i have updated the question with the log info.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: i use maven, I have a pom.xml file that I could post.  Also i looked inside the war file in JBoss and all the correct class files exist.  Do you want me to post the pom.xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a project based on your source code, added my own pom, and it works fine. You must have something peculiar somewhere else. You can take a look at the [working example on github](https://github.com/zzantozz/testbed/tree/master/stackoverflow/7692855-springmvc-controller-autowiring), or if you have git, you can check it out and run it yourself:

```
git clone git://github.com/zzantozz/testbed.git tmp
cd tmp/stackoverflow/7692855-springmvc-controller-autowiring
mvn jetty:run
```

Then visit http://localhost:8080/7692855-springmvc-controller-autowiring/glossarySearchResults, and you'll see the resulting page. The only thing I really changed in your code was to narrow down the list of context files in web.xml to contain only spring-service.xml.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks so much for doing that and I learned about github as a bonus!!  I was able to run the sample app that you built.  It loaded fine in JBoss, though ofcourse I am returning I 404 error.  So it isn't my JBoss so I am at a loss as to where it could be.  Just to make sure that it wasn't my DAOs I had commented all that stuff out.  It is very bare bones as it is now.  If the config files are correct why wouldn't the application context not load.  There error that is returned is a red herring and I don't know how to get to the source of the issue.  I have worked on this for 2 days!

Comment: If what I gave you worked, then I'd recommend starting from there and adding in the other parts of your project bit by bit until it stops working. I really can't think of anything that would make this fail in that way. Everything seems to be in its proper place.

Comment: Hi Ryan, in the test app that you built are you seeing :response.getWriter().print("My SIMS service: ?  All I get is a 404 error.  the log does not show an error thrown?

Comment: No. It works as expected for me. I get a web page with that message on it. Did you try it with jetty:run?

Comment: Hmmm, I am not familiar with jetty.  I will try to look it up now.

Comment: I ran the project with Jetty:run as the goal and it worked!! so this is strange, in JBoss I return a 404 error but in Jetty your app works fine.  I downloaded a clean version of JBoss but my app still doesn't work on the clean version of JBoss.  Since your app worked with Jetty and not on JBoss on my machine, do you think my issue is related to JBoss or the way my app is being built?

Comment: well I tried to run my app in jetty and it returned the same as JBoss

Comment: I was able to get my app working but it was kind of by accident..I accidently put the bean definition in spring-controllers.xml as well and it loaded?  My guess is, is that my app is for some reason not picking up the other configuration files.  From what you saw, they are in the web.xml file correctly right?

Comment: Yes, everything's correct in that sample project, as you saw from running it in Jetty. Are you sure you're requesting the right path in JBoss? Do you still get the error you posted originally? Moving your service bean to the controllers file will kinda make it work, and might be okay depending on your project, but it's not the "right" answer. That controllers file is for web-/view-layer beans, not your services. Also, your services probably need to be transactional, and your transaction manager probably lives in the other context files, so you'll run into the same problem there.

Comment: I was getting the same error but I think I have it working now!! In my troubleshooting I inadvertently commented out the listner in web.xml.  I think there initially was one issue and then I fixed that somehow down the line and then got accidentally commented it out in the web.xml.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, I really appreciate it and it got me to resolve my issue by using your test app that you created.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad you got it figured out :)

Answer (score 1):

are you not missing a

```
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

  </beans>
```

at the beginning of your `spring-services.xml` file?

Comment: hi,thanks for your response.  I only included the code that had my service in it because I thought the rest was boilerplate.  the schema definition is indeed in my file and I have updated my question with the full file.  Thanks, P.

Comment: I always have the following bean definitions when working with Spring-mvc and annotations:

   <context:annotation-config/>

   <!-- my beans -->

   <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Answer (score 1):

```
org.sims.service.SIMSService


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'glossarySearchController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.sims.service.SIMSService org.sims.web.controller.GlossarySearchController.simsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.sims.service.SIMSService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
```

I think you have not explicitly added  your package "org.sims.service" for classpath scanning.
You added only this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.sims.web.controller" />
```

Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotating your service class with `@Service`? This should cause Spring to pick it up via class-path scanning. It's just a special form of the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for your reply, I tried that as well but it is still returning the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

i got  the same problem.  < context:component-scan base-package="org.sims.web" /> Try instead of < context:component-scan base-package="org.sims.web.controller" />